# delegate を変数を介さずに直接実行したい

Tags: c#

C# にて、以下のように、delegate を変数を介さずに直接実行したいです。

```
int n = delegate()
{
    return 10;
}();
```

実際には上記コードは構文エラーになるので、以下のように変数を絡める必要があります。

```
Func<int> f = delegate()
{
    return 10;
};
int n = f();
```

変数を介さずに呼ぶことができないと困る、というわけではありませんが、何かしら直接呼べる方法があると少しだけ嬉しいです。他言語の例を挙げると、JavaScript等では前述のコードに似た記述ができますよね。何か良い解決策または代案ありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n = (new Func<int>(delegate() { return 10; }))();
```

Comment: 読みやすくするべく[edit]しました。インデント4つでコードブロックとして整形できます。

Comment: なるほど、、考えてみれば Func<int> の指定なしだと delegate の定義が曖昧になりますね。
ところでこのコードって以下のようにも書けるようですが、意味的には同じになりますかね？
int n = ((Func<int>)delegate(){ return 10; })();

Answer (score 3):

ラムダ式ですが

```
var n = new Func<int>(() => 10)();
```

も可能です。

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = ( (Func<int>)( () => 10) )();
```

補足:
delegate構文は、古い構文です。特別な理由が無ければ、ラムダ式を使用すべきでしょう。